# Next.js multi level routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with nested levels in Next.js but I can't understand how it's supposed to work.

The structure should be like: `/[rootCat]/[subCat1]/[subCat2]/[productId]`

Is it possible to achieve without using a custom server since I'd really like to benefit from the [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization)?

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs you can create this path using the file system navigation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-mclean-8nqwh?file=/pages/index.js

Following the example code you can define your parametric folders, and you can assign parameters by using `as` in `Link`

```
<Link
    href="/[rootCat]/[subCat1]/[subCat2]/[productId]"
    as="/root/category1/category2/category"
  >
    <a>Go To [productId] page</a>
  </Link>
```